# Get one child element per group

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am getting, with EF6, one advert by position as follows:

```
  var adverts = context.Adverts
    .Include(x => x.Files)
    .Where(x => x.Position <= 32)
    .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
    .GroupBy(x => x.Position)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First());
```

I get one advert per group and each advert has one file.

But what I really want is a file for each advert so I tried:

```
  var adverts = context.Adverts
    .Include(x => x.Files)
    .Where(x => x.Position <= 32)
    .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
    .GroupBy(x => x.Position)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First().Files);
```

In this case the value of the dictionary is empty.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Like this? `.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First().Files.First());`

Comment: The problem is the momento i use .files this property is null ... But if i don't use .files and check the adverts the files are not empty. Só this is strange

Comment: Btw with your code i get an error saying files is null ...

Comment: All adverts have at least one file?

Comment: Yes.  In fact with the code i tried i had only 1 advert so it was easy to check

Comment: Next time add the C# and Linq tags, and you'll get many more views

Comment: Try doing a `ToList` between `OrderBy` and `GroupBy`

Comment: I can't ... I do not want to load all files in Memory ... I need to get one property of the files.